# How to get real time data updates from web socket connection. Needed a hand, bro

Tags: python, websocket

G'day, frens. I was building a web socket connection to get Kline subscribe and get data push(Kline.update). It was built to check and receive data in real-time. > I really need a hand to figure this out. It appears the issue was from the get Kline.update part, something went wrong with this code if msg["method"] == "kline.update": Is there a better way to get Kline.update based on my code? ==

TLDR, the results didn't print out and error occurred. Ignore the key part. Any help would be appreciated. >
reference: https://viabtc.github.io/coinex_api_en_doc/futures/#docsfutures002_websocket023_kline_subscribe

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
import ssl
import certifi
import json
import logging
import time
import hashlib

WS_URL = "wss://perpetual.coinex.com/"
access_id = "xxx"
secret_key = "xxx"


ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
ssl_context.load_verify_locations(certifi.where())

async def ping(conn):
    param = {
        "id": 1,
        "method": "server.ping",
        "params": []
    }
    while True:
        await conn.send(json.dumps(param))
        await asyncio.sleep(3)

async def authorize(conn):
    current_time = int(time.time() * 1000)
    sign_str = f"access_id={access_id}&timestamp={current_time}&secret_key={secret_key}"
    token = hashlib.sha256(sign_str.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest().lower()
    param = {
        "id": 2,
        "method": "server.sign",
        "params": [access_id, token, current_time]
    }

    await conn.send(json.dumps(param))
    resp = await conn.recv()
    result = json.loads(resp)
    return result

# above for ws auth

async def connect_websocket():
    async with websockets.connect(WS_URL, ssl=ssl_context) as ws:

        result = await authorize(ws)
        print(result)

        asyncio.ensure_future(ping(ws))

        # Subscribe to kline
        param = {
            "method": "kline.subscribe",
            "params": ["MKRUSDT", "30"],
            "id": 5
        }
        await ws.send(json.dumps(param))
        resp = await ws.recv()
        result = json.loads(resp)
        print(result)

        # Get kline update

        while True:
            resp = await ws.recv()
            msg = json.loads(resp)

            if msg["method"] == "kline.update":
                print(msg)
        await asyncio.sleep(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(connect_websocket())
```

I'm expecting the code to run correctly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEVFJ.png)